# Check ts-node validity

Tags: typescript, ts-node

For my project ci/cd, I run `tsc --noEmit` to ensure my code typechecks. However, I have some scripts that I run with `ts-node`, and I recently got a bug where `tsc` said my code was valid but `ts-node` crashed (due to funky stuff with modules). Is there a way where I don't have to use `tsc` as a proxy for checking if `ts-node` will type-check/run correctly?

None of these options look like they are of much help: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#cli-flags